# Python 3 Turtle: How can I use the turtle.penup() function for all turtles with on one command?

Tags: python

I have 14 turtles currently on my program, and i want all of them to have `penup()` so they dont draw. Is there a way to make all of them have this function without using 14 lines of code?

eg. i want something like this: `allturtles.penup()`
instead of this: `turtle1.penup()`, `turtle2.penup()`...etc

i have tried making a list of all turtles such as this:

```
allShapes = [turtle1, turtle2... etc] 
allShapes.penup()
```

But this still doesnt work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to loop through all the elements in your `allShapes` list of turtles,

```
for turt in allShapes:
    turt.penup()
```